# Pick a color and then Chop image with that color into 7 easy pieces

Tags: image-processing

I have an image with 8 colors - (ROYGBIV and white) - I want to create 7 images - each has only one of the colors in the resulting image. I can do that fairly easily in GIMP.

Next I need to chop each of the 7 images into 7 layers - 7 pieces across with identical widths - with full height.

Finally I need to overlay the 7 layers on top of each other and see the resulting locations of the selected color.

Any ideas how to automate this image processing?

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking.  You want to generate 7 solid colored textures, then draw them all overlayed over each other?  What do you want to do this in?

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Let me take it one step at a time - first step I can do manually - so let's skip that - say I have the result - which is all of the RED color from the original picture - and all other colors are white / transparent.

Second step is to take that XCF image file and split it into 7 equal vertical pieces - making each a separate layer in an output image file.

The last step is to interlace those 7 layers so I can see what the combination of each of the layers looks like - showing what the RED from each layer looks like.

The tools to be used do not matter to me.

Comment: We can help you with automating this process, but it sounds like you want someone to do this for you.  Possibly consider hiring someone, or attempt to do it yourself and ask a more specific question about your implementation.  It is a good question, but it needs to be explained better as well.  I still am not understanding what you mean by the 7 layers.  Possibly include sample images of what your intended result would be.